# Python syntax error in repr.py when calling help function

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, pydoc

I am having a very odd problem with Python. Whenever I try to use the built-in **help** function, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 468, in __call__
    import pydoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 56, in <module>
    from repr import Repr
  File "repr.py", line 21
    def 
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have manually inspected the aforementioned files, but I don't see the error mentioned. I also tried deleting the **.pyc** files for the files mentioned in the trceback in the **/usr/share/python2.7** directory, but I am still having the issue.

My computer is running Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.

Comment: Do you have a file called `repr.py` in the current directory? That file is incomplete. Please, do not just delete `.pyc` files from your system folders, please *reinstall* python from packages (using your package manager).

Comment: Do you have a file called "repr.py" in your own code folder?

Comment: I think BrenBarn and Martijn have got the right guess (it was also what I was going to post), just booted up an un-touched VM of Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit, and it works fine... So unless you've made some strange changes...

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I did indeed have a file repr.py in my current directory. I can't believe I didn't catch that! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a file called repr.py in the current directory? That file is incomplete, and shadows the standard library `repr` module. You can see from the traceback that the file has no full path, only a local path. Rename it or remove it.

Please, do not just delete .pyc files from your system folders, please reinstall python from packages (using your package manager).